# XMLHttpRequest upload not working, only works without upload

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

This works (the event it's triggered and I receive a response from the server):

```
const fileForm = new FormData;

fileForm.append('file', this.inputUpload.files[0]);

const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.addEventListener('load', () => {

  if(xhr.status === 200) {

    console.log(xhr.responseText);

  }

});

xhr.open('POST', this.requestUrl);

xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', this.fileType);

xhr.send(fileForm);
```

But this not (the event is not triggered):

```
xhr.upload.addEventListener('load', () => {

  if(xhr.status === 200) {

    console.log(xhr.responseText);

  }

});
```

I want to use the `upload` property because I want to monitor the upload file progress.

Answer (score 0):

for this you need use

```
XMLHttpRequestEventTarget.onprogress
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequestEventTarget/onprogress

Comment: MDN says that I can use `oReq.upload.addEventListener("progress", updateProgress);` and `oReq.upload.addEventListener("load", transferComplete);`. So if `load` listener is not working, I've not tested `progress` listener yet. Also says "The download events are fired on the XMLHttpRequest object itself, as shown in the above sample. The upload events are fired on the XMLHttpRequest.upload object".

Comment: if you want see progress of the uploading file you must use "progress" event. And if load event not work, try "loadend"

Comment: `progress` works with `xhr.upload` object but neither `load` nor `loadend`. So I can monitor the progress but, why it's not working the load event?